# Remove common string from a string using jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can remove the 'tp.','ta.' and 'tta.' from below string from each place where it is coming

```
str = " tp.FirstName, tp.FamilyName, ta.DOB, tta.TypeOfLocation
WHERE

tp.DateStamp BETWEEN '2012-02-12 15:13:00' AND '2013-02-12 15:13:00'

AND tta.db_name_id =21
AND

tp.FirstName = 'Darlene'";
```

I need result as below:

```
FirstName, FamilyName, DOB, TypeOfLocation
WHERE

DateStamp BETWEEN '2012-02-12 15:13:00' AND '2013-02-12 15:13:00'

AND db_name_id =21
AND

FirstName = 'Darlene'";
```

Note: I have asked same question but this time I am using multiple removing string. Please assist me

Comment: I was tried .replace but something wrong there. now it is fixed thru 2nd answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can try this:

```
str.replace(/(tp\.)|(ta\.)|(tta\.)/g, '');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57Aym/2/) : check the console**

Comment: This won't work as `.` will match any character. Your output will have `DateSp BETWEEN` instead of `DateStamp BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    "aaa tp.bbb tf.ccc  tq.ddddd".replace(/[(tp\.)(tf\.)(tq\.)]/g, "")

    "aaa bbb ccc  ddddd"
```

But. Regular expressions can be an order of magnitude slower than 'normal' string operations. There are up to 10 browsers and 5 platforms these days where this has to be tested. Hard to believe but this example might be much faster:

```
     "aaa tp.bbbb  tf.ccc".split("tp.").join("").split("tf.").join("")
     "aaa bbbb  ccc"
```

Try and test. I would test on very large strings on mobile browsers first. It all depends *WHERE* do you perceive the primary usage is going to be.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
str = str.replace(/tp\./g,"").replace(/tta\./g,"").replace(/ta\./g,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `str.substring(str.indexOf("."))` for each word in the string.

Answer (score -1):

```
var newstring = str.replace(".tp","").replace(".ta","").replace("tta.","");
```

that would work

Comment: Replace (when used with strings) only replaces the first occurrence.